# Extracting HTML tag content with xpath from a specific website

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I am trying to extract the contents of a specific tag on a webpage by using lxml, namely on Indeed.com.

Example page: [link](https://www.indeed.com/cmp/The-Habitat-Company/jobs/Janitor-eb00a371b5460027?sjdu=QwrRXKrqZ3CNX5W-O9jEvUx5EqoNSCDS7Hcvh7EMNpiZzZ9eiZPJIDkC3NDWbdUNmWvfZSevVvzi4YXBmkjFd8Bkdc4qgiTbLPuuF_N0vKU&tk=1cigks4msafthee0&vjs=3)

I am trying to extract the company name and position name. Chrome shows that the company name is located at

```
"//*[@id='job-content']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span[1]"
```

and the position name is located at

```
"//*[@id='job-content']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/b/font"
```

This bit of code tries to extract those values from a locally saved and parsed copy of the page:

```
import lxml.html as h

xslt_root = h.parse("Temp/IndeedPosition.html")
company = xslt_root.xpath("//*[@id='job-content']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span[1]/text()")
position = xslt_root.xpath("//*[@id='job-content']/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/b/font/text()")
print(company)
print(position)
```

However, the print commands return empty strings, meaning nothing was extracted!

What is going on? Am I using the right tags? I don't think these are dynamically generated since the page loads normally with javascript disabled.

I would really appreciate any help with getting those two values extracted.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that indeed specifies in their Terms and Conditions that " Unless you have been specifically permitted to do so in a separate, written agreement with Indeed, you agree that you will not crawl, scrape, reproduce, duplicate, copy, sell, trade or resell the Site for any purpose". Just throwing this out there. I'll still look into the issue, assuming you won't use this out of the bounds of indeed's legal setting.

Comment: Agreed. I want to point to this related meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329321/unethical-possibly-illegal-assistance

Comment: That's a fair observation, @dennlinger. I won't try to weasel my way out of this and just admit that I'm writing a program that generates partially personalized cover letters. It does **not** do so in a loop and it basically automates a copy-paste process which I had been employing. I guess that falls under "scraping," but so might my copy-paste process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
company = xslt_root.xpath("//div[@data-tn-component='jobHeader']/span[@class='company']/text()")
position = xslt_root.xpath("//div[@data-tn-component='jobHeader']/b[@class='jobtitle']//text()")
['The Habitat Company']
['Janitor-A (Scattered Sites)']
```

Once we have the `//div[@data-tn-component='jobHeader']` path things become pretty straightforward:

1. select the text of the child span `/span[@class='company']/text()` to get the **company** name
2. `/b[@class='jobtitle']//text()` is a bit more convoluted: since the job title is embedded in a font tag. But we can just select any descendant text using `//text()` to get the **position**.

   An alternative is to select the `b` or `font` node and use `text_content()` to get the text (recursively, if needed), e.g.
   `xslt_root.xpath("//div[@data-tn-component='jobHeader']/b[@class='jobtitle']")[0].text_content()`

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm really new to xpath and truly appreciate a breakdown like this. I'll mark your post as answer, but @dennlinger's post also lead me to investigate an issue of the local copy of the page either downloading and being properly referencing, or the server serving only raw html with no style or JS.

Comment: @radi0 totally agree, one you have 15 reputation you can go ahead and upvote the answers to reward the effort put forth.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your assumption, it seems that the content on the page is loaded dynamically, and is thus not present during loading time.
This means you can't access the elements from your downloaded HTML file (if you do not believe me, try to look for `job-content` in the actual file on your computer, which will only contain placeholders and descriptors.

It seems you would have to use technologies like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to perform this task.
Again, I want to stress that whatever you are doing (automatically), is a violation of indeed.com's Terms and Conditions, so I would suggest not to go too far with this anyways.

Comment: You are (partially) correct and bring up a very important point. I've noticed that the html file saved locally was either properly rendered, or it wasn't (plain html and no style). I've tried both requests and urllib.request - both would randomly produce either fully rendered pages or half-baked pure html. My solution was to write an error handler that attempts to use wp78de's solution, and if it fails, it uses a direct xpath that I've found to be consistend in the "incomplete" webpage.